# How can I insert a space for an Action name that has more than one word in it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do this to display a breadcrumb on a page:

```
@if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] != "MainController")
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
            .ToString(), "Index",
            ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())
    </li>
}
@if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] != "Index")
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
            .ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(),
             ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())
    </li>
}
```

This works well to display "Controller" or "Controller > Action" (without the ">" - am using jBreadcrumbs to display a divider).

However, if my Action names are like `ScheduleAppointment`, for example, then it's displayed as "Controller > ScheduleAppointment" whereas I'd like it displayed as "Schedule Appointment" (i.e., a space is inserted).

Is it possible to do that in a `@{}` function on the page? Or do I have to write an extension?

In either case a code example would help greatly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom attribute with "DisplayName" property and put it on your action. Then in view you can access current controller

```
ViewContext.Context
```

and get current action's custom attribute instance using reflection and get "DisplayName" property value. 
Or you can set property in ViewBag and then use it in view.

Comment: How would I do that, because I cannot figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly you cannot figure out? How to create custom aatribute you can find here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sw480ze8.aspx.
To get custom attribute's property using reflection use something like this
ViewContext.Context.GetType().GetMethod(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()).Attributes.First(x=>x is CustomAttribute).DisplayName

Comment: i thik if you're going to answer the question, you should give as full an answer as possible. as it stands, your current anser is more like a comment. i only say this to help both yourself and the OP in the pursuit of quality